# Akka Streams split Stream for Error handling

Tags: scala, akka, reactive-programming, akka-stream, akka-http

I'm using akka http and streams to fulfill API requests.
When the request is invalid I want to return a 400 and if it's valid, i want to proceed with the computation and return the result afterwards.
The Problem I'm facing is, that the Payload I'm receiving from the POST request is a Source and I cannot convert it into 2 Streams (one for valid and one for invalid input data) and complete the request correct.

```
path("alarms")(
  post(entity(asSourceOf[String]) { message =>
    val flow = message.via(Flow[String].map((it) => 
         Try(if valid(it) then it else throw Exception("Wrong input"))
    ))
    complete(repository.create(flow).run) // <-- here I only want to pass all events that are valid. For the other events complete(HttpResponse(NotFound, entity = "Invalid input")) should be used
  })
)
/// The signature of the repository.create looks like that
def create(message: Source[String, NotUsed]): RunnableGraph[Future[Done]]
```

Comment: You probably should use `Broadcast` or `alsoTo` to process your source in two different ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the akka-http `handleExceptions` directive, sth like this:

```
val exceptionHandler = ExceptionHandler {
 case ex: RuntimeException =>
   complete(HttpResponse(NotFound, entity = "Invalid input"))
}

path("alarms")(
  handleExceptions(exceptionHandler) {
    post(entity(asSourceOf[String]) { message =>
      val flow = message.via(Flow[String].map((it) =>
        Try(if valid(it) then it else throw new RuntimeException("Invalid input"))
      ))
      complete(repository.create(flow).run)
  })
  }
)
```

Doc:

https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/execution-directives/handleExceptions.html

https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/exception-handling.html

There is also `handleRejections` directive for even more control - see https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/execution-directives/handleRejections.html

Comment: Thanks. This is good first approach to handle invalid inputs. I think for now I will use this one. It would be interesting to know if there is method without throwing an exception, but directly using  2 sinks and completing with both of them.